# Difference between orderBy of hibernate and Collections.sort()

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

What is the difference between using order by of hibernate and Collections.sort() of Java? The time complexity of Collections.sort() is O(nlogn) and using orderBy must be O(1). However, the db processing must have some overhead too. Is it okay to use Collections.sort() in cases where using orderBy is not possible?

Comment: `Is it okay to use Collections.sort() in cases where using orderBy is not possible?` - Yes, why not?

Comment: orderBy() is optimized only when the database server can use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one. Generally they should both be O(nlogn) (since the database also has to apply a sorting algorithm and it is not better than the sorting algorithm in Collections).

I would use the database's orderBy if possible (*), since you then can limit the amount of data that are sent from the database (at least in cases where you'r only interested in the first part of the matching data).

(*) There are situations where you want you want to implement a "weird" sort order (ie "sort by the 2nd letter of the third word"), and then it is better to do it in Java, but in most cases orderBy is sufficient and hence preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that an `order by` on the db applies on all the rows. While you can only apply Collections.sort to "loaded" rows.

So, if you have 1000 rows, and you want to select the first 10 according to an order, to use `Collections.sort` you would need to get all rows before sorting, while with `order by` you would only select the 10 you want.